# Line numbers with side-by-side diff

Tags: shell, diff, vimdiff, sdiff

I want to write a shell script that diffs two files, and dump the result into another file.

I find `sdiff` to be more intuitive than just `diff`.  However, `sdiff` doesn't print out the line numbers of where the differences are.  I also tried `vimdiff`, which shows me line numbers, but I'm not sure how to dump the results into a file from a shell script.

So far, this is what I am using:

```
sdiff -s file1 file2
```

Is there a way to get side-by-side diffs with line numbers?

Comment: The solution is to use diff. The answer is here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34874/diff-output-line-numbers

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice tool for this: `meld`

To install: `sudo apt-get install meld`

You can check differences between two or more files, also between directories.